# Cassandra : Single Large Instance vs Multiple Small Instances

Tags: cassandra

I am planning to deploy Cassandra database for my project. I need to deploy it with a cost around 150$ per month.

I am expecting a around 20000 hits (read, update & write combined) per minute. All will be direct hit on compound keys.

I am planning to go with Vultr vps. 
Should I go for single big instance like ( 6 CPU, 24GB memory ) or 3 small instances like ( 2 CPU, 8 GB Memory ) ?

Comment: I'd recommend the multiple instances, if only because it will force your clients to properly specify quorum, replication, _etc_; you will _eventually_ want to horizontally scale your C* cluster, and sooner is better (so that you know how) rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have at least 4 cores and 16GB of RAM and SSD is mandatory for high volume of data. Currently I have 9 instances at aws type i3.xlarge.
It's not only the amount of writes and reads, C* also requires background tasks to maintenance. It's really difficult to configure C* to work with only 8GB. It can start work but latter you are going to get lots of OOM. I have also started like that!

Comment: For development environment I am running cassandra in single node, 1 core, 1GB. Java heap memory we can control in the configuration right ?

Comment: Yes, you just need to tweak jvm.options at /etc/cassandra